# What database should i use for cross domain json calls with authentication?

Tags: javascript, database, encryption, cross-domain, userscripts

I am creating a userscript that decrypts encrypted text based on the user that writes the text. I need to use a database to store and call the decryption keys inside the browser.

So for example i want a twitter user A to receive encrypted posts from twitter user B.Then the userscript opens a window to authenticate the twitter user A to use the database with the decryption keys.It then identifies that the post it received is from twitter user B and asks the database to send the decryption keys required for twitter user B.

So the database must:

```
1.Use authentication to access the user's keys
2.Have a javascript API
3.Send the decryption keys in jsonp format so it can be cross domain
4.Have a share function so user A can share with user B the decryption keys upon request
```

Is there any opensource database that can do all this?

Comment: The database (any database) would store and retrieve the keys, encrypted data and whatever else. The other tasks are, um, not a database's job.

Comment: You will need to write a web application to do this and host it on some server that is visible to both users.  The database is only part of the application which you need to write, and just about any open-source database will work.  PHP and Python are two free application languages with a lot of support for building webapps.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on cross domain authentication as part of a large project for users to be able to stay logged in across related localized websites.  As Quassnoi states, a large part of your task is not DB related.

My own preference was to use .NET and Javascript.  The sites actually have datastores in XML for everything localized. Which is unavailable externally, so SQL was used for a central user database so that its easy to connect to: store/retrieve from anywhere.
This g search gives plenty of good examples:
[https://www.google.dk/search?q=asp.net+cross+domain+authentication](https://www.google.dk/search?q=asp.net%20cross%20domain%20authentication)

Using .NET allows easy creation of a webservice for your needs that can handle the encryption and decryption of collected data and passing it on.

As for opensource database, in reality a managed hosting account supporting MS SQL can be sorted for as little as $4 per month.  Otherwise, I'd opt for MySql and use a dataconnector to communicate with the app and save the $4 dollar cost.